# insert,update in single button clickin winforms

Tags: c#

I am not getting, how to do insert and update of the data in C# WinForms on single button click.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "data source=Sai;database=kaur; user id=sa;password=azxc;";


        cn.Open();

        string gen;
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            gen = "Male";
        else
            gen = "Female";
        string clas = null;
        clas = comboBox1.Text;

        string section = null;
        section = comboBox2.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into studetail values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + gen + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + clas + "','" + section + "')";

        cmd.Connection = cn;

        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (n > 0)
            MessageBox.Show(n + " Row Inserted.");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Insertion failed.");

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from studetail ", cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Do you have any (unique) id in each row?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a deletion before the insertion:

```
        private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeletePerson(id); // add this
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();

            ...
        }


        public void DeletePerson(int id)
        {
            using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(credentials))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;   
                cmd.CommandText = "delete from studetail where someUniqeIdColumn = " + id;        
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
        }
```

- `Using` responsible to dispose the connection.
- Consider using [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx) or [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/).
- You are exposed to [SQL injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First off the SQL query isn't quite right. It should look something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO studetail (columnName1, columnName2, ...columnNameN)  
VALUES (value1, value2, ...valueN);
```

Where the column names are the columns where you want data to be inserted, and the values are the data you want inserted into said columns.

You should also be disposing the connection by wrapping the connection within a using statement.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
con.Open();
//rest of code that needs a connection here
}
```

Additionally, you need to be wary of SQL injection. I highly suggest [reading this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) example from the MSDN website. It will give you an example of using an SQL Update and avoiding SQL injection with use of `SqlCommand.Paramaters` property.

You should also have a Primary Key in your database tables, if you don't already, so you can uniquely identify each record in a table.

To do an update and a save on the same button, you will need to check if a row already exists for the data that is being edited. This when a Primary comes in handy. You will want to check your database to see if a record already exists

```
SELECT 1 FROM studetail WHERE <Condition>
```

The `WHERE` condition will be the way you uniquely identify (a Primary Key) a row in your table. If the rows in the table are uniquely identified, the above SQL statement will return `1` if a value exists, which means you can `UPDATE` or `0` if no record exists, so you can `INSERT`